# Prediction values in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, probability

Can someone help me with the code for getting the predicted probability values? My model is working fine and is giving me predictions as 1 and 0 however I need the probability values also. The code is in two python files. The first file uses the training data set to create the map file. The second python file (scoring file) uses the map file on the test data to predict. Can someone let me know the code I should insert to get the probability values.
The below code is from the scoring file and here I need the code the get the probability values

```
pred = model.predict(X.values)
data["Predicted"] = pred

# I NEED THE CODE HERE TO GET THE PROBABILITY VALUES. 

data.to_excel(r'result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: For the next time, kindly see how to format appropriately your code blocks (done it for you this time)...

Comment: What exactly is your model (SVM, logistic regression...)??

Comment: Not all ML algorithms provide probabilities. Check the documentation of your ML model and see if there is any predict_proba() method.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your model has `predict_proba` method.

The usage is same as the same `predict` method.

```
prob = model.predict_proba(X.values)
```

**Edit:**

Some of the learning model implementations from sklearn provide the `predict_proba` method. It is not a metric but as I said, a method of the class of the learning model.

For example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
# after split you have X_train,y_train,X_testy_test
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
proba = model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: Hi thanks I used prob = model.predict_proba(X.values) but the code is giving an error. I am using sklearn but what exactly do I need to import from sklearn to be able to use the mode.predict_proba?  See below and please let me know if anything is missing                                                                                               from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, precision_score, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

Comment: What model are you using? Let me edit my answer to include an example

Comment: @Manish we have already asked *what model* are you using (it seems it is RandomForest); and please *do not* use the comments space to provide code - **edit & update** your post instead (such code should be part of your question in the first place)...!

Comment: I could not edit my initial question so request you all to see my answer where I have stated the error I am getting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am no longer able to edit my question so putting it here.

Thanks for all the help. I am using random forest model. This is my code and the line 4 below is giving an error. If I remove line 4, the code runs but in the final excel file I do not get the probabilities but only the predictions as 1 and 0. Can someone please let me know how to resolve this error. The last line of the error says 
       ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

```
pred = model.predict(X.values)
data["Predicted"] = pred
prob = model.predict_proba(X.values)
data["Pred Value"]= prob   - this line causes error
data.to_excel(r'result.xlsx', index=False)'
```

Thanks

Comment: prob = model.predict_proba(X.values)[1] for probabilities of the positive class

Comment: thanks but the 4th line data["Pred Value"]= prob  still gives an error